# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Network Error). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, jsx

I am facing this issue while submitting a form. I want to take inputs from the form and show it into the list.
I am getting an error which is
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Network Error). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

this is the add user form

````
import { Row, Col, Form, Input, Select, DatePicker, Radio, InputNumber, Upload, Spin } from 'antd';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import FeatherIcon from 'feather-icons-react';
import { RecordFormWrapper } from './Style';
import { PageHeader } from '../../../components/page-headers/page-headers';
import { Cards } from '../../../components/cards/frame/cards-frame';
import { Button } from '../../../components/buttons/buttons';
import { Main, BasicFormWrapper } from '../../styled';
import { usernewDataSubmit } from '../../../redux/crud/usernew/actionCreator';
// import Heading from '../../../components/heading/heading';

const { Option } = Select;
const dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD';

const AddNew = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isLoading, } = useSelector(state => {
    return {
      isLoading: state.UserNewCrud.loading,
    };
  });

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    join: '',
    dob: '',
  });

  const handleSubmit = values => {
    dispatch(
      usernewDataSubmit({
        ...values,
        join: state.join,
        dob: state.dob,
        id: new Date().getTime(),
      }),
    );
    form.resetFields();
    dispatch(usernewFileClear());
  };

  const onChange = (date, dateString) => {
    setState({ join: dateString });
  };

  // const props = {
  //   name: 'file',
  //   action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
  //   multiple: false,
  //   showUploadList: false,
  //   headers: {
  //     authorization: 'authorization-text',
  //   },
  //   onChange(info) {
  //     if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
  //       dispatch(usernewFileUploder(info.file.originFileObj));
  //     }
  //     if (info.file.status === 'done') {
  //       // message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
  //     } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
  //       // message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
  //     }
  //   },
  // };

  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader
        // buttons={[
        //   <Button className="btn-add_new" size="default" key="1" type="primary">
        //     <Link to="/admin/crud/usernew-view">View All</Link>
        //   </Button>,
        // ]}
        ghost
        title="Add New User"
      />
      <Main>
        <Row gutter={15}>
          <Col xs={24}>
          <Form name="sDash_validation-form" form={form} layout="vertical" onFinish={handleSubmit}>
          <Row gutter={30}>
            <Col md={12} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="name" label="Full Name">
                <Input placeholder="Enter you full Name" />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={12} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="email" rules={[{ type: 'email' }]} label="Email Address">
                <Input placeholder="name@example.com" />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={12} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="phone" label="Phone Number">
                <InputNumber type="number" placeholder="+44 2546 5236" style={{ width: '100%' }} />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>

            <Col md={12} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="address" label="Full Address">
                <Input placeholder="Enter your complete address" />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>

            <Col md={12} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="postal_code" label="Postal/Zip/Pin Code">
                <InputNumber type="number" placeholder="160071" style={{ width: '100%' }} />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={12} xs={24}>
            <Form.Item name="country" initialValue="" label="Country">
                  <Select style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    <Option value="">Please Select</Option>
                    <Option value="russia">Russia</Option>
                    <Option value="india">India</Option>
                    <Option value="uk">United Kingdom</Option>
                    <Option value="usa">United States</Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={8} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="state" label="State">
                <Input placeholder="Enter state Name" />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={8} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="city" label="City">
                <Input placeholder="Enter city name" />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>

            <Col md={8} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item rules={[{ type: 'object', whitespace: true }]} label="Date of Birth">
                <DatePicker onChange={onChange} format={dateFormat} style={{ width: '100%', padding: '12px' }} />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={8} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item rules={[{ type: 'object', whitespace: true }]} label="Joining Date">
                <DatePicker onChange={onChange} format={dateFormat} style={{ width: '100%', padding: '12px' }} />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>

            <Col md={8} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="gender" initialValue="" label="Gender">
                <Radio.Group>
                  <Radio value="male">Male</Radio>
                  <Radio value="female">Female</Radio>
                  <Radio value="others">Others</Radio>
                </Radio.Group>
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={8} xs={24}>
              <Form.Item name="status" initialValue="" label="Status">
                <Radio.Group>
                  <Radio value="active">Active</Radio>
                  <Radio value="inactive">Inactive</Radio>
                </Radio.Group>
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            {/* <Col md={8} xs={24}>
                <Form.Item name="address_type" initialValue="active" label="Address type">
                  <Radio.Group>
                    <Radio value="home">Home</Radio>
                    <Radio value="work">Work</Radio>
                    <Radio value="other">Other</Radio>
                  </Radio.Group>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col> */}
          </Row>
          <Form.Item>
            <div className="add-user-bottom text-right">
              <Button
                className="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"
                type="danger"
                onClick={() => {
                  return form.resetFields();
                }}
              >
                Reset
              </Button>
    
              <Button htmlType="Save" type="primary">
                            {isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit'}
                          </Button>
            </div>
          </Form.Item>

          {/* <div className="sDash_form-action mt-20">
              <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary" size="large">
                Submit Form
              </Button> 
            </div>*/}
        </Form>



            {/* <RecordFormWrapper>
              <Cards headless>
                <Row justify="center">
                  <Col xl={10} md={16} xs={24}>
                    <BasicFormWrapper>
                      <Form
                        className="add-record-form"
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                        layout="vertical"
                        form={form}
                        name="addnew"
                        onFinish={handleSubmit}
                      >
                        <figure className="pro-image align-center-v">
                          <img
                            src={
                              url === null
                                ? require('../../../static/img/avatar/profileImage.png')
                                : `https://demo.jsnorm.com/laravel/strikingdash/${url}`
                            }
                            alt=""
                          />
                          <figcaption>
                            <Upload {...props}>
                              <Link className="upload-btn" to="#">
                                <FeatherIcon icon="camera" size={16} />
                              </Link>
                            </Upload>
                            <div className="info">
                              <Heading as="h4">Profile Photo</Heading>
                            </div>
                            {isFileLoading && (
                              <div className="isUploadSpain">
                                <Spin />
                              </div>
                            )}
                          </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <Form.Item name="name" label="Name">
                          <Input placeholder="Input Name" />
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="email" rules={[{ type: 'email' }]} label="Email">
                          <Input placeholder="example@gmail.com" />
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="country" initialValue="" label="Country">
                          <Select style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                            <Option value="">Please Select</Option>
                            <Option value="bangladesh">Bangladesh</Option>
                            <Option value="india">India</Option>
                            <Option value="pakistan">Pakistan</Option>
                            <Option value="srilanka">Srilanka</Option>
                          </Select>
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="city" initialValue="" label="City">
                          <Select style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                            <Option value="">Please Select</Option>
                            <Option value="dhaka">Dhaka</Option>
                            <Option value="mymensingh">Mymensingh</Option>
                            <Option value="khulna">Khulna</Option>
                            <Option value="barisal">Barisal</Option>
                          </Select>
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="company" label="Company">
                          <Input placeholder="Company Name" />
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="position" label="Position">
                          <Input placeholder="Position" />
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item label="Joining Date">
                          <DatePicker onChange={onChange} style={{ width: '100%' }} format={dateFormat} />
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="status" label="Status">
                          <Radio.Group>
                            <Radio value="active">Active</Radio>
                            <Radio value="deactivated">Deactivated</Radio>
                            <Radio value="blocked">Blocked</Radio>
                          </Radio.Group>
                        </Form.Item>
                        <div className="record-form-actions text-right">
                          <Button size="default" htmlType="Save" type="primary">
                            {isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit'}
                          </Button>
                        </div>
                      </Form>
                    </BasicFormWrapper>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Cards>
            </RecordFormWrapper> */}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Main>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddNew;


//This is actionCreator file

import { notification } from 'antd';
import actions from './actions';
import { DataService } from '../../../config/dataService/dataService';

const addNotificationSuccess = () => {
  notification.success({
    message: 'Your Record has been Submited',
  });
};

const addNotificationError = err => {
  notification.error({
    message: err,
  });
};

const deleteNotificationSuccess = () => {
  notification.success({
    message: 'Your Record has been Deleted',
  });
};

const deleteNotificationError = err => {
  notification.error({
    message: err,
  });
};

const updateNotificationSuccess = () => {
  notification.success({
    message: 'Your Record has been updated',
  });
};

const updateNotificationError = err => {
  notification.error({
    message: err,
  });
};

const {
  usernewAddBegin,
  usernewAddSuccess,
  usernewAddErr,

  usernewReadBegin,
  usernewReadSuccess,
  usernewReadErr,

  usernewUpdateBegin,
  usernewUpdateSuccess,
  usernewUpdateErr,

  usernewDeleteBegin,
  usernewDeleteSuccess,
  usernewDeleteErr,

  usernewSingleDataBegin,
  usernewSingleDataSuccess,
  usernewSingleDataErr,
} = actions;

const usernewDataSubmit = data => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewAddBegin());
      const response = await DataService.post('/create', data);
      await dispatch(usernewAddSuccess(response.data.data));
      await addNotificationSuccess();
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewAddErr(err));
      await addNotificationError(err);
    }
  };
};

const usernewDataRead = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewReadBegin());
      const query = await DataService.get('/view-all');
      await dispatch(usernewReadSuccess(query.data.data));
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewReadErr(err));
    }
  };
};

const usernewCrudGetData = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewReadBegin());
      const query = await DataService.get('/view-all');
      await dispatch(usernewReadSuccess(query.data.data));
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewReadErr(err));
    }
  };
};

const usernewDataSearch = searchItem => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewReadBegin());
      if (searchItem !== '') {
        const query = await DataService.get(`/search/${searchItem}`);
        await dispatch(usernewReadSuccess(query.data.data));
      } else {
        try {
          const query = await DataService.get('/view-all');
          await dispatch(usernewReadSuccess(query.data.data));
        } catch (err) {
          await dispatch(usernewReadErr(err));
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewReadErr(err));
    }
  };
};

const usernewDataUpdate = (id, data) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewUpdateBegin());
      await DataService.post(`/update/${id}`, data);
      await dispatch(usernewUpdateSuccess());
      updateNotificationSuccess();
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewUpdateErr(err));
      updateNotificationError(err);
    }
  };
};

const usernewDataDelete = ({ id, getData }) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewDeleteBegin());
      const data = await DataService.get(`/delete/${id}`);
      await dispatch(usernewDeleteSuccess(data));
      await getData();
      deleteNotificationSuccess();
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewDeleteErr(err));
      deleteNotificationError(err);
    }
  };
};

const usernewDataSingle = id => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await dispatch(usernewSingleDataBegin());
      const query = await DataService.get(`/view/${id}`);
      await dispatch(usernewSingleDataSuccess(query.data.data));
    } catch (err) {
      await dispatch(usernewSingleDataErr(err));
    }
  };
};


export {
  usernewDataRead,
  usernewDataSearch,
  usernewDataSubmit,
  usernewDataDelete,
  usernewCrudGetData,
  usernewDataSingle,
  usernewDataUpdate,
};

//Below is actions file.

const actions = {
  USERNEW_ADD_BEGIN: 'USERNEW_ADD_BEGIN',
  USERNEW_ADD_SUCCESS: 'USERNEW_ADD_SUCCESS',
  USERNEW_ADD_ERR: 'USERNEW_ADD_ERR',

  USERNEW_READ_BEGIN: 'USERNEW_READ_BEGIN',
  USERNEW_READ_SUCCESS: 'USERNEW_READ_SUCCESS',
  USERNEW_READ_ERR: 'USERNEW_READ_ERR',

  USERNEW_UPDATE_BEGIN: 'USERNEW_UPDATE_BEGIN',
  USERNEW_UPDATE_SUCCESS: 'USERNEW_UPDATE_SUCCESS',
  USERNEW_UPDATE_ERR: 'USERNEW_UPDATE_ERR',

  USERNEW_DELETE_BEGIN: 'USERNEW_DELETE_BEGIN',
  USERNEW_DELETE_SUCCESS: 'USERNEW_DELETE_SUCCESS',
  USERNEW_DELETE_ERR: 'USERNEW_DELETE_ERR',

  USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_BEGIN: 'USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_BEGIN',
  USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_SUCCESS: 'USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_SUCCESS',
  USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_ERR: 'USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_ERR',

  usernewAddBegin: () => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_ADD_BEGIN,
    };
  },

  usernewAddSuccess: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_ADD_SUCCESS,
      data,
    };
  },

  usernewAddErr: err => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_ADD_ERR,
      err,
    };
  },

  usernewReadBegin: () => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_READ_BEGIN,
    };
  },

  usernewReadSuccess: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_READ_SUCCESS,
      data,
    };
  },

  usernewReadErr: err => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_READ_ERR,
      err,
    };
  },

  usernewUpdateBegin: () => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_UPDATE_BEGIN,
    };
  },

  usernewUpdateSuccess: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
      data,
    };
  },

  usernewUpdateErr: err => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_UPDATE_ERR,
      err,
    };
  },

  usernewDeleteBegin: () => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_DELETE_BEGIN,
    };
  },

  usernewDeleteSuccess: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_DELETE_SUCCESS,
      data,
    };
  },

  usernewDeleteErr: err => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_DELETE_ERR,
      err,
    };
  },

  usernewSingleDataBegin: () => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_BEGIN,
    };
  },

  usernewSingleDataSuccess: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_SUCCESS,
      data,
    };
  },

  usernewSingleDataErr: err => {
    return {
      type: actions.USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_ERR,
      err,
    };
  },
};

export default actions;

//Below is reducers file

import actions from './actions';

const {
  USERNEW_ADD_BEGIN,
  USERNEW_ADD_SUCCESS,
  USERNEW_ADD_ERR,

  USERNEW_READ_BEGIN,
  USERNEW_READ_SUCCESS,
  USERNEW_READ_ERR,

  USERNEW_UPDATE_BEGIN,
  USERNEW_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
  USERNEW_UPDATE_ERR,

  USERNEW_DELETE_BEGIN,
  USERNEW_DELETE_SUCCESS,
  USERNEW_DELETE_ERR,

  USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_BEGIN,
  USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_SUCCESS,
  USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_ERR,
} = actions;

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const initialStateSingle = {
  data: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const usernewCrudReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, data, err } = action;
  switch (type) {

    case USERNEW_ADD_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case USERNEW_ADD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data,
        error: false,
        loading: true,
      };

    case USERNEW_ADD_ERR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: err,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_READ_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case USERNEW_READ_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data,
        error: false,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_READ_ERR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: err,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_DELETE_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case USERNEW_DELETE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: false,
        data,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_DELETE_ERR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: err,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_UPDATE_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case USERNEW_UPDATE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: false,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_UPDATE_ERR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: err,
        loading: false,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const usernewSingleCrudReducer = (state = initialStateSingle, action) => {
  const { type, data, err } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...initialStateSingle,
        loading: true,
      };

    case USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...initialStateSingle,
        data,
        error: false,
        loading: false,
      };

    case USERNEW_SINGLE_DATA_ERR:
      return {
        ...initialStateSingle,
        error: err,
        loading: false,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export { usernewCrudReducer, usernewSingleCrudReducer };

// Below is dataService file

import axios from 'axios';
import { getItem } from '../../utility/localStorageControl';

const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

const authHeader = () => ({
  Authorization: `Bearer ${getItem('access_token')}`,
});

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_ENDPOINT,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${getItem('access_token')}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

class DataService {
  static get(path = '') {
    return client({
      method: 'GET',
      url: path,
      headers: { ...authHeader() },
    });
  }

  static post(path = '', data = {}, optionalHeader = {}) {
    return client({
      method: 'POST',
      url: path,
      data,
      headers: { ...authHeader(), ...optionalHeader },
    });
  }

  static patch(path = '', data = {}) {
    return client({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: path,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { ...authHeader() },
    });
  }

  static delete(path = '', data = {}) {
    return client({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: path,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { ...authHeader() },
    });
  }

  static put(path = '', data = {}) {
    return client({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: path,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { ...authHeader() },
    });
  }
}

/**
 * axios interceptors runs before and after a request, letting the developer modify req,req more
 * For more details on axios interceptor see https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors
 */
client.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  // do something before executing the request
  // For example tag along the bearer access token to request header or set a cookie
  const requestConfig = config;
  const { headers } = config;
  requestConfig.headers = { ...headers, Authorization: `Bearer ${getItem('access_token')}` };

  return requestConfig;
});

client.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    /**
     * Do something in case the response returns an error code [3**, 4**, 5**] etc
     * For example, on token expiration retrieve a new access token, retry a failed request etc
     */
    const { response } = error;
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (response) {
      if (response.status === 500) {
        // do something here
      } else {
        return originalRequest;
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
export { DataService };```
````

Comment: Can you reduce the code? which line throws this error?

Comment: @slideshowp2
while clicking on a submit button it throws this error but the line is not mentioned in the error.
all the files the are linked together, that is why I put all the code above